# CasperJS test won't return after execution

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm having a problem getting casperjs test to exit after execution, I have to hit CTL-C to exit execution.

misc.js

```
var require = patchRequire(require);

var site = {
    goToSite: function (url) {
        casper.start(url, function checkSite() {
            this.test.assert(this.getCurrentUrl() === url, 'Url is: ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
            this.test.assertHttpStatus(200, 'HTTP status code 200 OK');
        });
    },

    login: function () {
        casper.then(function fillTheForm() {
                this.fill("form[action='/auth/login']", {
                    'email': 'login@email.com',
                    'password': 'pass'
                }, true);
            }
        );
    }
};

module.exports.site = site;
```

test.js

```
var system = require('system');
var misc = require('./misc');
casper.options.logLevel = "debug";
casper.options.verbose = true;

casper.on("resource.error", function(errorCode, errorString, url, id){
    this.echo(errorString);
});

casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace){
    this.echo(msg);
});

casper.on("remote.message", function(message){
    this.echo(message);
});

casper.test.begin('Cow can moo', 2, function suite(test) {
    var url = "http://ym.cms2cms/auth/login";
    misc.site.goToSite(url);
    misc.site.login();

    casper.run(function () {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

terminal

```
PASS Url is: http://ym.cms2cms/auth/login
PASS HTTP status code 200 OK
PASS 2 tests executed in 1.596s, 2 passed, 0 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.
```

http://screencast.com/t/5ZmTZLK3C5Bk

Comment: Are you on windows? Are you sure that you have to hit Ctrl+C and not simply hit enter?

Comment: On linux http://screencast.com/t/5ZmTZLK3C5Bk

Comment: I have to hit Ctrl+C, but when I comment out this code //misc.site.login(); test exit after execution

Comment: add events - nothing change ...

casper.on("resource.error", function(errorCode, errorString, url, id){
    this.echo(errorString);
});

casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace){
    this.echo(msg);
});

casper.on("remote.message", function(message){
    this.echo(message);
});
@Artjom B

Comment: Similar problem here with a strange resolve: [CasperJS: how to exit script execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482357/casperjs-how-to-exit-script-execution)

Comment: Not working 

    casper.then(function() {
        this.exit();
    });

Comment: Does it work if you copy and paste the misc.js code into test.js; well, in fact, going even further, if you bring in `goToSite()` and `login()` into your test suite function? If so, maybe it is something about modules?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the number from calling the test like so:

`casper.test.begin('Cow can moo', function suite(test) {`

According to Casper JS Api, it refers to the Number planned, you are specifying 2 with only 1 test. I find removing it altogether works well, and only specify if you need to.

**Note from the doco:** The planned argument is especially useful in case a given test script is abruptly interrupted leaving you with no obvious way to know it and an erroneously successful status.